# JBoss Forge CLI is slow

Tags: windows, command-line-interface, jboss-forge

Just installed JBoss Forge via SDKMan and try to use the autocomplete feature in the CLI. Each autocomplete takes about 2-3 seconds, so I get the feeling that something's wrong with the configuration (Win 10).

Any Idea how I could speed up the CLI?

**Update:** just booted a linux on the same machine and gave Forge a try. Also installed via GVM, autocomplete works much better...

Comment: Did you find anything helpful why it is so slow on windows? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: No, unfortunately not. I switched over to linux...